# Aurelia - getting TypeError: palModule.initialize is not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, aurelia

Trying to setup my first Aurelia Hello World project using ASP.NET Core. Can't get past the above error.

3 files, index.html, app.html, app.js:

Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body aurelia-app>
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import("aurelia-bootstrapper");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.html:

```
<template>
    <div>${message}</div>
</template>
```

app.js:

```
export class App {
    constructor() {
        this.message = "Hello from Aurelia";
    }
}
```

The ASP.NET Core StartUp.cs :

```
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                //await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise everything standard. Ran the following to install Aurelia:

```
jspm install aurelia-framework
jspm install aurelia-bootstrapper
```

Pretty basic but getting error:
[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He6Ek.png)

Comment: Have you seen their [skeleton projects](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation)? Might help to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to run `aurelia-pal-browser` because this will enables us to run the framework in different environments.

Try this code :

```
jspm install npm:aurelia-pal-browser
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked first time.

Comment: Always Welcome !

Comment: +1 I'm going through Scott Allen's Building Apps with Aurelia course on Pluralsight, and ran into this same issue.  I've built Aurelia apps with the skeleton projects, but now trying to build one from the ground up.